# Why is the code not working for strings with same length?

Tags: python, string, loops

Following is the code that I have written that counts the number of substrings of length 2 that are common to both the input strings.Also the substrings should be at the same location in both the strings.

```
def string_match(a, b):
  count=0
  shorter=min(len(a),len(b))
  for i in range(shorter):
    if(a[i:i+2]==b[i:i+2]):
      count=count+1
    else:
      continue
  return count
```

The code runs fine for strings with different length but gives wrong answer for strings with same length. for eg: 'abc' and 'abc' should return 2 but it is returning 3 and also 'abc' and 'axc' should return 0 but it is returning 1.
 The above problem can be solved by changing range(shorter) to range(shorter-1), but I am not understanding why?
Also if possible suggest me changes in the above code that can count same substrings regardless of the positions in the two strings.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try `print(a[i:i+2])` and see what output you get. The last value will only have 1 character.

Comment: `continue` is not necessary here.

Comment: use `range(shorter-1)` instead of `range(shorter)`, as for the last element you end up accessing out of range index

Comment: @pramod: The OP said that he tried that and it works, he wants an explanation why.

Comment: Eg. shorter = 3 and then on accessing a[3, 5]  or b[3,5], will raise 'list index out of range'

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting this. The user has some code that doesn't work as expected -- they've found a fix for it, but want to properly understand why it helps. That's a perfectly valid question, in my mind.

Comment: Probably being downvoted because the OP could have very very easily debugged this themselves simply by putting in some print statements to examine the comparison result which increments count rather than posting the question on here. Would have been better to guide the OP to have discovered for themselves why their code doesn't work - if they can't figure out how to do this in such a small bit of code how will they fare with some real world code?

Comment: They are clearly new at coding. What seems obvious to me and you isn't to everyone, and you've gotta start somewhere. Besides, they asked the question in an _excellent_ way, IMO. Wanting to understand _why_ something works, and not just being content that "okay it works now" is the perfect attitude to become a great programmer. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some good old print debugging should make things clearer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#coding=utf8

def string_match(a, b):
    count=0
    shorter=min(len(a),len(b))
    print 'comparing', a, b
    for i in range(shorter):
        x = a[i:i+2]
        y = b[i:i+2]
        print 'checking substrings at %d: ' % i, x, y
        if x == y:
            count=count+1
        else:
            continue
    return count


for a, b in (('abc', 'abc'), ('abc', 'axc')):
    count = string_match(a,b)
    print a, b, count
```

And the output:

```
so$ ./test.py 
comparing abc abc
checking substrings at 0:  ab ab
checking substrings at 1:  bc bc
checking substrings at 2:  c c
abc abc 3
comparing abc axc
checking substrings at 0:  ab ax
checking substrings at 1:  bc xc
checking substrings at 2:  c c
abc axc 1
```

See the problem? You're always comparing a substring of length 1 at the end. This is because `'abc'[2:4]` will give you just `'c'`.

So, you'd need to end one step earlier (or, more generally, `n-1` steps earlier when you're comparing substrings of length `n`). This is exactly what your `-1` change would do, which is why it helps.

With the `-1` change:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#coding=utf8

def string_match(a, b):
    count=0
    shorter=min(len(a),len(b))
    print 'comparing', a, b
    for i in range(shorter-1):
        x = a[i:i+2]
        y = b[i:i+2]
        print 'checking substrings at %d: ' % i, x, y
        if x == y:
            count=count+1
        else:
            continue
    return count


for a, b in (('abc', 'abc'), ('abc', 'axc')):
    count = string_match(a,b)
    print a, b, count
```

And the new output:

```
so$ ./test.py 
comparing abc abc
checking substrings at 0:  ab ab
checking substrings at 1:  bc bc
abc abc 2
comparing abc axc
checking substrings at 0:  ab ax
checking substrings at 1:  bc xc
abc axc 0
```

Comment: Well done for showing the OP one simple way to debug this, perhaps they can learn to do it for themselves

Comment: That's the idea. :)

Answer (score 2):

Examine your `for` loop

```
for i in range(shorter):
    if a[i:i+2]==b[i:i+2]:
        count=count+1
    else:
        continue
```

[`range(n)`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range) by default goes from 0 to `n-1`. So what happens in the case of `n-1`? Your loop is attempting to access the `n-1`th to `n+1`th characters. But the smaller string only has `n` characters. So Python simply returns that letter instead of two letters, and so two strings of equal length with the same last character would give a false positive. This is why `range(shorter - 1)` is necessary.

Also the use of `continue` is redundant as by default the loop will continue anyways

To find substrings of length 2 *anywhere* in the strings this should suffice

```
def string_match(string1, string2):
    string1subs = [string1[i:i+2] for i in range(len(string1) - 1)]
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(string2) - 1):
        if string2[i:i+2] in string1subs: count += 1
    return count
```

Creates a list `string1subs` that contains all substrings of length 2 in `string1`. Then loops through all substrings of length 2 in `string2` and checks if it is a substring of `string1`. If you prefer a more concise version:

```
def string_match(string1, string2):
    string1subs = [string1[i:i+2] for i in range(len(string1) - 1)]
    return sum(string2[i:i+2] in string1subs for i in range(len(string2) - 1))
```

Exact same version using [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#sum) and the fact that in Python, `True` is equal to 1.

Comment: This code would be more efficient if `string1subs` were a set instead of a list - sets are much better at item lookups than lists. Just change `string1subs = [...]` to `string1subs = {...}`.

Comment: @Rawing: More efficient, but if the OP wanted to count double occurrences of a substring it would be much more difficult than simply using a list

Answer (score -2):

Best way is not to use any index access at all:

```
def string_match(a, b):
    count = 0
    equal = False
    for c, d in zip(a,b):
        count += equal and c == d
        equal = c == d
    return count
```

or with generator expression:

```
from itertools import islice
def string_match(a, b):
    return sum(a1 == b1 and a2 == b2
        for a1, a2, b1, b2 in zip(a, islice(a,1,None), b, islice(b,1,None)))
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the question of why the poster's code is not working correctly.

Comment: Yes, and this also gives the OP a whole new level of behaviour obfuscation for them to struggle with when things don't quite work they way they hope for. Well done!